# Is it possible to define a symmetry group for the Einstein metric?

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, group-theory

I was just wondering if there exists a group of transformations that act on the metric such that the EFE are invariant. At first I thought it would be the group of 2nd roots of unity. That is, the set {1,-1} under multiplication because you can multiply the metric by -1 to change the signature and 1 to keep it the same. Then I thought perhaps it would be the group of Jacobians of every possible coordinate system, but I believe you would have to apply the Jacobian to every tensor in the equation for that to work...It would make most sense to me if this symmetry group was the group of all spatial and temporal translations. But I'm most interested to know whether or not the group of 2nd roots of unity could be defined as the symmetry group.

Comment: I think you're trying to ask for the [isometry group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry_group).

Comment: General Relativity is constructed to be invariant under general local coordinate transformations - the symmetry group ought to be $Gl(4)$.

Comment: @Neuneck: That would be the case if space-time was a four dimensional vector space with no additional structure. So no, it is not GL(4).

Comment: @MBN: Can't all complete metric spaces be though of as vector spaces...?